# React - API Function Does Not Have Access to Context API

Tags: reactjs

While creating a reusable, importable function for making API calls I ran into the issue of not being able to access the Context API to get the auth token.

Importable Function:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Context } from '../Context';
import axios from 'axios';

const FetchDataFunction = (method, endpoint, params) => {

  const [context] = useContext(Context); // the line throwing the error

  const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: `...`,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer 11111111111111111', //need this from API Context
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  });

   ...make api request...
 }
```

Component trying to use the function

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import FetchDataFunctionfrom '../../../../FetchDataFunction';
import { Context } from '../../../../Context';

const ComponentName = () => {
   const [context] = useContext(Context); //works!

   useEffect(() => {
     async function fetchData() {
         var result = await FetchDataFunction('get','endpoint', {params: {...}});
     }

    fetchData();
   },[]);
}
```

Error: 
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See link for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

I need access to the context api to get auth tokens as well be able to update the context api when auth tokens expire. Thus passing the context to the function is not an option. React/Redux is complex and seems like it will be replaced by Context.

Anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: I see that you are using `useContext` hook in a function rather than using it in a `functionalComponent`, You can use hooks only in functional component

Comment: Thanks sumanth -  Every call needs to use a token from the Context, check for expiration and on fail make another call to get new token and update context if necessary. So adding this functionality to every call within every component is not an option. Need a central function to make these calls for all components. do you have a proposed solution?

Comment: you can use redux in place of context

Answer (score 0):

context is meant for functional Components and not functions. Why not read context value and pass in your function as parameter?

Comment: Thanks Gaurav.  Every call needs to use a token from the Context, check for expiration and on fail make another call to get new token and update context if necessary.So I would need to pass both the context and the function to update the context to the function every time. . and there may be more than one call per component. Surely there must be a better way, no?

Answer (score 0):

I used a custom hook that would fetch the data.

See here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

```js
const useApi = (method, endpoint, params) => {

  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
  const [context, setContext] = useContext(Context);

  const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: `URL`,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + context.user.bearer, 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      //Just did a GET for this, but you can easily change this to be more universal
      const res = await api.get(endpoint,params);
      setResponse(res);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [] );

  return response;
}
```

Then in the component file:

```js
import { useApi } from './../../../../Utilities/Hooks/use-api.js';

/* ..... */
  const something= useApi(
    'get',
    'something/',
    {params: {foo: bar}},
  );
  
  /* .... */
   useEffect( () => {

    if (something){
      // Do something with the API call data you get back here
    }


 },[something]);
```